# Crystal: Autoupdating table names in database expert

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

It is more of an annoyance rather than real issue: when in Crystal reports you change the data source to one with different name (and do all the linking old columns to new columns) all the table names in Field explorer and (obviously) in formulas are changed. But the Database expert still shows the old table/view name!

Let me show this on example: Lets say I change `TABLE_1` with column `EQUIPMENT` to `VIEW_1` with column UNIT. Via the datasource location I can do the substitution and link old column EQUIPMENT to new one - UNIT.

But when I check either Datasource location or database expert it will be still showing old TABLE_1 (if you check the columns in the link tab you will notice that the TABLE_1 has now column UNIT instead of EQUIPMENT).

This can be quite annoying and frankly bit dangerous, especially if you return to report after a longer while. Is there somewhere a setting that allows to autoupdate table names in the database expert?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the report it will create tables and each table will be linked to a datasource table. So the report table will have a name and datasource , which might be the same. When you change the datasource the datasource of the table will be updated but the report table name will remain the same. Think about this name as an alias. It might differs from th datasource name if you use the same table multiple times

Comment: Yes, I know its an alias, I can even rename it in the database expert. I was just wondering if there is a setting to match the name of the alias to the new (after changing data source) table. Sadly I don't think there is :(

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it is available too

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is auto update option in crystal reports but one thing you can do is to use `Verify Database` option under `Database` tab whenever you update the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually edit table names in Database expert, there's no  automatic way (and like Lan already answered, it is generally not possible).